# What is the meaning of xmlns:android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Why is everyone use http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ?
Do I need sometimes to use something different that this url ?
Who need this url ?, is something like package I mean what is the point with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 2):

**`xmlns`** defines an **XML Namespace**.

The URI that's used, even if it doesn't point to an existing resource, generaly points to *([quoting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace))* a *resource under the control of the author or organisation defining the vocabulary*.

For more informations, take a look at [XML namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

Answer (score 1):

> Why is everyone use http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android ?

Because that describes the namespace. It means that you can tell the difference between the `orientation` attribute used there, and an `orientation` attribute used in some other XML language.

> Do I need sometimes to use something different

Yes. If you want to use elements or attributes from a different namespace.

> that this url ?

It isn't a URL. It just looks like one to help avoid two people using the same name for their namespace.